# Naming `django-admin.py' vs 'django_admin.py'

Tags: django

In Django's `bin` folder, names `django-admin.py`which is separated by `-`,
while others such as `easy_install`  are isolated by underscore '_'.
Django does not follow the PEP in naming,
what is the particular advantage for this setting,
or what kinds of unexpected problems will happen if Django's author names it as 'django_admin.py' instead of 'django-admin.py'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `pip install django`, inside each virtual environment you create, the [`django-admin`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/bin/django-admin.py) is made to work as a CLI (command line interface) directly from your terminal.
The convention of CLI command names is using dashes `-` instead of `_` underscores.

Notice that when you execute `django-admin` you're not executing it with `python manage.py django-admin` but directly as `django-admin`.